# What is wrong with this Strawflower?

Tags: houseplants, diseases, plant-care

I have a tom thumb/dwarf strawflower growing in a gallon plastic pot. It's not supposed to get higher than 15 inches and the plant next to it came from the same packet.
It only has a few flowers on it, is long and lanky compared to the healthy, shorter, bushier plant next to it with more flowers overall.

The Strawflower's leaves are curling and droopy, and it's a bit  bowed over. I'm keeping them inside until it warms up since i started them a bit earlier than i should have.

Some known problems are: Not enough sunlight, and ethylene from the furnace. However, these dont seem to be affecting my other otherwise healthy plant that is right next to it, watered about the same, if not a bit more since it takes in water quicker.

What is wrong with it, and how can i fix it?[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the winter plants have a tendency to 'stretch' towards the light. especially when there's not enough,that could explain why their so long. It's really tough to 'winter' certain plants but,try to keep it going until the spring and you can cut it back and start it over. The curling leaves could mean a change in temp. Do you have a drip tray underneath? Just watch your watering, not too much and not too little. Think Spring.

Comment: Yeah, I have a drip tray underneath. Good thing, too.